# Using a var in an <img src> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to work out my own photo album when I encountered an error. It's a syntax error but after trying out a number of different ways of writing the code it just wont work.

Here's what I did. I made a **var image** which contains the *string* file path (using string manipulation) of the image (I am not to use PHP just yet, so it can only accept photos from a given folder named "images" on the base directory) and another **var imgSource** to contain the actual image itself using the *var image*.

The code is:

```
var image = "images/" + $(".inputImage").val().split('\\').pop();
var imgSource = $('<img src = image alt = "Image not found" class = "card-img-top">');
```

for some reason, even without the apostrophes, the tag  reads the word *image* as the filepath (string) not as *variable* I've created.

Comment: `$('<img src="'+ image +'" alt="Image not found" class="card-img-top">');` Try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use

```
var imgSource = $('<img src="' + image + '" alt="Image not found" class="card-img-top">');
```

Comment: Best to also use `""` around the `src` attr value, just in case the image name contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
var image = "images/" + $(".inputImage").val().split('\\').pop();
var imgSource = $('<img src="' + image + '" alt="Image not found" class="card-img-top">');
```